# AngularJS - Strange behavior when using $watcher on an external AngularJS service variable

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript

In my controllers constructor I call the following function:

```
  constructor(private $scope, private $log : ng.ILogService, private lobbyStorage, private socketService) {
  this.init();
}

private init(){
  this.lobbyData = [];
  this.initializeLobbyData();

  // DOM related initialisation
  this.chatWindow = $('.chat-output');

  var self = this;
  this.$scope.$watch(
    function () {
      return self.socketService.chatHistory
    },
    function (newValue, oldValue) {
      if(typeof newValue.body !== "undefined" &&  newValue.body.data.length > 0){
        // Delete existing records
        self.chatWindow.empty();

        for (var i = 0; i < newValue.body.data.length; ++i) {
          console.log(newValue.body.data[i].body.userName)
          self.chatWindow.append($('<span><strong>' +  newValue.body.data[i].body.userName + '</strong>&nbsp' +  newValue.body.data[i].body.message + '<br></span>'));
        }
      }

    }
  );

  this.socketService.setUpWebsocketService();

}
```

This is suppose to watch an external variable from an AngularJS Service which uses websocket.

When I debugg the code in the browser (Chrome), the callback function of the `$watcher` gets called twice and eventually loads the data to the chatWindow.

[image]

As soon as I run the web app without the debugger, the data won't get loaded.

[image]

What I do need to do, is clicking for e.g a button on the page. For some reason **any kind of interaction (e.g button, anker)** with the page seems to result in showing the data to the chatWindow.

[image]

The same interaction isn't necessary when I am in the debugger window. The data gets loaded without any interaction from my side.

Does anyone have an explanation for that?

Comment: `socketService.chatHistory` does any initialization? Maybe using debugger you let service the time to do some initialization. The twice call is a normal behavior, you had to check newValue vs oldValue to check if value are really changed.

Comment: `socketService.chatHistory` is defined as a simple property on the AngularJS service. Totally forgot about checking the values. Thank you for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because `$watch` only runs in the digest cycle, i.e. after `$scope.$apply()` is called by someone. Angular does that for you when an `ng-click` happens, but your websocket library probably doesn't do that, so you have to call `$scope.$apply()` manually whenever a result comes back through the websocket.

See also [AngularJS' `$scope` documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/scope).

Unrelated: careful, your `$('<span>'... + someUserName)` line is probably a XSS vulnerability in your service, allowing users to inject e.g.  tags from their chat messages.

Comment: Thank you very much and also for the hint with the XXS vulnerability. It is just a dummy implementation on the client side and every message is getting checked for malicious input on the server. About your answer - I got the following error "$apply already in progress error". I will give it a try with the following code snippet, which should solve the problem of an already pending digest cycle. https://coderwall.com/p/ngisma/safe-apply-in-angular-js

Comment: Your problem is that there must only be one `$apply` call within a browser event. So you're probably calling `$apply` at the wrong place - you should do so in the very outermost handler of your web sockets callback. Do not call `$apply` e.g. in the `$watch` above or other places.

The `$$phase` thing you quote is a hack and a last resort, it usually causes more trouble than it fixes.